# Changing values in column selectively. Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

for example i have a fruit dataset that contains the name and colour. How do i change the values in colour column based on the fruit name that i select?

```
       Name          Color
       Apple         NaN
       Pear          Green
       Pear          Green
       Banana        Yellow
       Watermelon    Green
```

I have a rough idea but i have no idea how to code it.

```
     df[Name] == Apple then df[color] == Red
```

Comment: For the sample case provided, you can do: `df.loc[df['Name']=='Apple', 'Color'] = 'Red'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use [.apply()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
In [83]: df
Out[83]: 
         Name   Color
0       Apple     NaN
1        Pear   Green
2        Pear   Green
3      Banana  Yellow
4  Watermelon   Green

In [84]: df['Color'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Red' if x.Name == 'Apple' else x.Color, 1)

In [85]: df
Out[85]: 
         Name   Color
0       Apple     Red
1        Pear   Green
2        Pear   Green
3      Banana  Yellow
4  Watermelon   Green
```

Another simpler way is to use [.ix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
In [94]: df
Out[94]: 
         Name   Color
0       Apple     NaN
1        Pear   Green
2        Pear   Green
3      Banana  Yellow
4  Watermelon   Green

In [95]: df.ix[df.Name == 'Apple', 'Color'] = 'Red'

In [96]: df
Out[96]: 
         Name   Color
0       Apple     Red
1        Pear   Green
2        Pear   Green
3      Banana  Yellow
4  Watermelon   Green
```